# How to credit customer with stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe and i need to credit user with Stripe.

I know how to credit myself with a customer, but can I credit a customer ?

I'm using the Stripe PHP Library

Comment: You want to refund a charge you created?

Comment: No, I want to pay a customer, but it's not possible, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe support send me an email, and they said that is not possible.

Comment: You'd have to use the deprecated recipients API or managed accounts as part of Stripe Connect